# unwanted URL switch and security concern. looking for a simpler or better solution

Tags: php, security, redirect, data-structures, get

I couldn't do it any shorter :-/

I'm having a problem with my php project concerning redirects and $_GET.

I hope you will help me :)

Lets say I have these 3 folders in the root of my Webserver.

```
/root
   /themes
         /page.php
   /project1
         /index.php
         /content.php
   /project2
         /index.php
         /content.php
```

`/themes` contains a php file called `/page.php`
`/page.php` contains a dynamic PHP/HTML structure or theme, which I can use for different content files.

`/project1` and `/project2` contain mostly HTML content files which get included by `/page.php`.

`/project1` and `/project2` are the root folders for 2 different domains, so each contains an `index.php`.

**Now the problem:**
In order to get the websites for each domain to work I have to redirect the user to `/themes/page.php`, because thats where the functionality is and then include the correct content files.
To let `/page.php` know what content file out of `/project1` or `/project2` it has to load I use a redirect for `index.php` to fill `$_GET` ,like this :

```
header("Location: root-domain/themes/page.php?path=project1&file=content1");
```

That way page.php gets to know the path and filename of the requested file, by taking it from GET.

**BUT:**
That way the user gets to know each folder and each filename, even of some php files. I don't know if that's good?
And the URL changes from the requested URL into the URL of my webserver root.

Does one know a better solution?

Thanks! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think there is a solution, you just need to use mod_rewrite, which is a module for Apache. With that, you could redirect all your URL requests to this one specific page of yours. Unfortunatelly, the "magic" behind mod_rewrite is little bit more complex, so I recommend you [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for further uses.

But for now, just check if you have a mod_rewrite turned on in server configuration, then simply create a file called *.htaccess* in directory *project1* (or any other) and insert this little piece of code in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?([^/.]+)?/?$ /themes/page.php?path=$1&file=$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Hit save, and that should be it. Now every page request goes through */themes/page.php*.

And by the way, you definitely shouldn't be exposing script names in url.